# Помогите с условием видимости объекта

Tags: android

Есть два прогресс бара (это условность) вращающихся. По умолчанию они невидимы. При условии один из них становится видимым, при другом условии видимый становится невидимым, а невидимый видимым. Все просто. Все это дело происходит в методе `OnReceive`. По началу я использовал примерно такой код, но со статичной картинкой

```
        if (U<=-30 && U>-500) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressBarLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
        }

        if (U>=30 && U<500) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
            mProgressBarLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (U<30 && U>-30) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mProgressBarLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Я не придавал значения, потому что все работало. В случае с прогресс баром по моей логике все тоже должно работать, нужно делать просто видимым или невидимым. Но происходит так, как будто этот прогресс бар пересоздается раз за разом и анимация вращения дергается на первом фрейме. `OnReceive` работает, соответственно только тогда, когда поступают какие-то данные. Если ничего не поступает, то прогресс бар начинает нормально вращаться

Comment: Вам нужно вызывать `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` один раз при старте операции, а в процессе только изменять прогресс (если нужно).

Comment: А нужные прогресс восстановить не получится при изменении видимости того или иного прогрессбара?

Comment: @woesss очевидные вещи говорите, я понимаю. вот в этом и вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы правильно было?

Comment: Если Вам всё очевидно, в чём проблема-то... Покажите больше кода, что бы и нам было очевидно, что у Вас там делается. По этому куску могу предложить только костыль в виде дополнительной проверки прогрессбаров на видимость типа `if (U<=-30 && U>-500 && mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)`

Answer (score 1):

Добавил проверку на то, видим объект сейчас или нет. Теперь анимация плавная

```
        if (U<=-30 && U>-500)
        {

            if (mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) return;
            else
                {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mProgressBarLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

        }

        if (U>=30 && U<500)
        {

            if (mProgressBarLeft.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) return;
            else
            {
                mProgressBarLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }

        if (U<30 && U>-30) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mProgressBarLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```